# Match Month-Year of one Date to the Day-Month of another Date

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro that assigns values based on matches between dates. My macro is supposed to loop through a column of dates and match the month-year of each date to a row with other dates. If there is a match, a value in a corresponding column needs to be copies over. The issues I am running into is comparing an extracted month-year of one date with the month-date of another. A simple version of what I want the data to look like is this:

[image]

As you can see, the value is copied over into the horizontal part that corresponds to the date next to the value. It is copied over a fixed number of times depending on the term.

The issue I am running into is in matching the date. I am trying to compare the month-year of the Date with the month-year in row 1, but my script is only functioning when there is an exact match, i.e. when the date in column B matches the date in row 1. So if a date in column B is 1/1/2011, then it gets copied into the correct cell, but otherwise it does not get copied at all. Here is the script I am working on (note that I only have it set up for quarterly terms - when I get that to work, I will add the other terms to the If-statement.

```
Sub End_Collate()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long, lastrow_reps As Long
    Dim reps As Variant, reps_list As Variant
    Dim min_date As Date, min_date_format As Date, date_diff As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("data")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Rep_Commission")

    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set reps_list = ws.Range("A3:A" & (lastrow))
    date_diff = DateDiff("m", min_date, Date)

    'loop through each sheet and add in the correct dates to the correct range
    For Each reps In reps_list
        min_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ws2.Range("H2:H" &
        Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row))
        i = 0
        With wb.Worksheets(reps.Text)
            Do While DateDiff("m", min_date, Date) <> 0
                Worksheets(reps.Text).Range("S1").Offset(0, i).Value = min_date
                min_date = DateAdd("m", 1, min_date)
                i = i + 1
            Loop
        End With
    Next reps

    For Each reps In reps_list
        i = 0
        j = 0
        lastrow_reps = Worksheets(reps.Text).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastcolumn = Worksheets(reps.Text).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 2 To lastrow_reps
            'currently this is quarterly - once I get it to work I will add options for daily, monthly etc.
            If Worksheets(reps.Text).Cells(i, 11).Value = "Quarterly" Then
                With Worksheets(reps.Text)
                    For j = 18 To lastcolumn
                        If (DatePart("m", .Cells(i, 8)) & DatePart("y", .Cells(i, 8))) = (DatePart("m", .Cells(1, j)) & DatePart("y", .Cells(1, j))) Then
                            .Cells(i, j) = .Cells(i, 18)
                        Else                     'Do nothing (will add error handling here)
                        End If
                    Next j
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    Next reps

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong interval for `DatePart` ([the documentation is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/datepart-function)).

`"y"` is the *day of* the year, not the year. Your code looks like it should work if you replace the interval with `"yyyy"`.

This demonstrates:

```
Public Sub DatePartIntervals()
    Debug.Print DatePart("y", Now)
    Debug.Print DatePart("yyyy", Now)
End Sub
```

Comment: you are so right - now I feel like an idiot. Using "yyyy" does work - thanks!